# How to print 2-D array stored in hashmaps in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, hashmap

Sorry a newb here

```
String [][] myExampleArray = {{"string1", ..., "string100"},{"string1", ..., "string100"}};
```

I want to put them in hashmap and my code looks like this

```
Hashmap <String[], String[]> mappedArrays = new Hashmap<>();
mappedArrays.put(myExampleArray[0], myExampleArray[1]);
```

I tried doing this:

```
for (var mappedArray : mappedArrays.entrySet())
  System.out.println(mappedArray.getKey() + " ==== " + mappedArray.getValue());
```

and it only shows one result:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@372f7a8d ==== [Ljava.lang.String;@8efb846
```

how would I print all mappedArrays in key/value pair? Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your keys and values are arrays of strings, not strings. If you want to "stringify" your arrays, you can use `Arrays.toString`, like so:

```
for (var mappedArray : mappedArrays.entrySet())
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mappedArray.getKey()) + " ==== " + Arrays.toString(mappedArray.getValue()));
```

If you wanted the `i`th string in `myExampleArray[0]` to be mapped to the `i`th string in `myExampleArray[1]` instead, your HashMap will need to be of type `HashMap<String, String>`, and you'll need to loop over the arrays to put each `(String, String)` pair in.